# Adding Pictures in Google Maps

Tags: image, google-maps

I need to add my picture as a popup to google maps specific address may be in latitude,longitude OR specific to my address in Google Maps. is it possible or any 
google maps api json like parameter configuration. pls let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google map markers, and google map infowindow might serve your purpose.
Have a look :
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindow

You can provide the photos in the html parameter to the infowindow, see this example from documentation:
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html